# Adding a list of fig object to a subplot in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a generic plotting tool eg.:
from the main function i call a function that plot a single (error plot)
here I want to use this function to generate different plots and after combine these into a single sub plot. eg.:

from the main function I would call the plot function 3 times with different data:

```
`my_figs=list()
my_figs.append(error_plot("Fig_1", [1,2,3], [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]))
my_figs.append(error_plot("Fig_2", [a,b,c], [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]))
my_figs.append(error_plot("Fig_3", [2a,2b,3c], [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]))
```

the plotter function is as this:

```
def error_plot(title, x_data, y_data, x_name, y_name):

xtick_size = list()
for i in range(0, len(x_data)):
    xtick_size.append(i)

mean_y_data = list()
var_y_data = list()

for i in range(len(y_data)):
    mean_y_data.append(np.nanmean(y_data[i]))
    var_y_data.append(np.nanvar(y_data[i]))

plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.errorbar(xtick_size, mean_y_data)
ax.plot(xtick_size, mean_y_data)
plt.xticks(xtick_size, x_data)
ax.set_xlabel(x_name)
ax.set_ylabel(y_name)
ax.set_title(title)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=45)
ax.grid()

return plt
```

my problem is I dont know how to make a subplot from this list, is there any smart way of doing this ? current what i tried is (not working):

```
def create_sub_plot(title, plots):

plot_rows = len(plots)
i = 1
for fig in plots:
    ax = plt.subplot(plot_rows, 1, i)

    i+=1
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way matplotlib is working is that you have **one** figure. Inside this figure you can have an arbitrary amount of subplots.

You thus need to design your code such that the plotting function takes an axes as argument and manipulates this axes by adjusting labels, ticks, and plotting to it.

```
def error_plot(ax, title, x_data, y_data, x_name, y_name):
    ax.plot(x_data, y_data)
    # do other stuff to the axes

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

error_plot(ax1, "Fig_1", [1,2,3], [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]))
error_plot(ax2, "Fig_2", [a,b,c], [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]))
error_plot(ax3, "Fig_3", [2a,2b,3c], [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]))
```